# How can I call a function that is defined below where it is called?

Tags: c++, function

I'm making an endless text based game in C++ and have multiple functions that need to be able call eachother. I don't seem to be able to do this, because functions need to be defined above where they are called to work, and I can't have them both defined above eachother. How do I make it able to call a function defined below it?

I've tried moving the definition of the functions above eachother, but since one of them needs to call a function defined below it, it  won't work.

```
#include <iostream>

void function_one()
{
    int user_selection = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter \"1\" to call function 2.\n";

    switch (user_selection) {
        case 1:
            function_two();
            break;
    }

}

void function_two()
{

    int user_selection = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter \"1\" to call function 1.\n";

    switch (user_selection) {
        case 1:
            function_one();
            break;
    }

}

int main()
{
    function_one();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2019, and the error I get is "C3861 'function_one': identifier not found."

Comment: It should be `function_two()` not found. And the solution is to put this: `void function_two();` above `void function_one(){ ...` you could also use a header to declare the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply declare the functions on the top, and then you can define them later:

```
#include <iostream>

void function_one();
void function_two();

int main()
{
    function_one();
    return 0;
}

void function_one()
{
    int user_selection = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter \"1\" to call function 2.\n";

    switch (user_selection) {
        case 1:
            function_two();
            break;
    }
}

void function_two()
{
    int user_selection = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter \"1\" to call function 1.\n";

    switch (user_selection) {
        case 1:
            function_one();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your functions inside class. Then create object of that class. And call your functions on that object. Like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class SomeName{public:

    void function_one()
    {
        int user_selection = 0;
        std::cout << "Enter \"1\" to call function 2.\n";

        switch (user_selection) {
            case 1:
                function_two();
                break;
        }

    }

    void function_two()
    {

        int user_selection = 0;
        std::cout << "Enter \"1\" to call function 1.\n";

        switch (user_selection) {
            case 1:
                function_one();
                break;
        }

    }

} someName;

int main()
{
    someName.function_one();
    return 0;
}
```